# Minimum current at parallel resonance

Tags: impedance, resonance

Does parallel resonance in an AC circuit always result in maximum impedance thus minimum current? If not ,why? I've read this only happens when the parallel branch 'conductances are constant' but have no idea what this means.

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: The inductor has a parasitic series resistance.

Comment: Don't drip-feed the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Does parallel resonance in an AC circuit always result in maximum
>   impedance thus minimum current?

Only when the frequency of the applied signal is correct. A parallel inductor and capacitor have an impedance thus (product over sum): -

\$Z_p = \dfrac{j\omega L}{1 - \omega^2LC}\$

This impedance rises to infinity when the denominator is zero and this happens when: -

\$\omega^2LC = 1\$ or \$\omega = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{LC}}\$

Or, more conventionally F = \$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$

Current drawn from the signal driving the parallel resonant circuit can theoretically acquire a zero value but, there are still voltages present across the individual L and C components and, this results in a large circulating current swishing back and forth between the inductor and capacitor. But, theoretical impedance seen by the driving source can be very high.

> I've read this only happens when the parallel branch 'conductances are
>   constant' but have no idea what this means

I also have no idea what this means.

Comment: This applies when zero resistance is assumed. What happens when the branches have resistances?

Comment: @MdAjwaadZamanQuashef Then what you have is a damped resonant circuit, lower peak, wider bandwidth (see Q factor - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor) **but there is still a peak impedance (minimum current) at the resonant frequency**. It just means the impedance isn't 'infinite'.

Comment: @MdAjwaadZamanQuashef see this wiki page for a few configurations with resistance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit

Comment: Yes but in that case does it ALWAYS have to result in minimum current?

Comment: Resonance is by definition the state of unity power factor, not necessarily meaning maximum/minimum current.

Comment: 1) It depends what you mean by minimum current - current is maximized swishing between L and C but, from the outside world, looking at LC, the impedance appears very high and hence current is very low. 2) I agree.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read this only happens when the parallel branch 'conductances are constant' but have no idea what this means.

You probably mis-heard, or you or your instructors mis-translated between some other language and English.

We often say that parallel resonance is found when the admittance (of the parallel combination) is **real**, meaning the admittance value is a real number rather than a complex number. For a series impedance it would be when the impedance has a real value.

This would also result in a power factor of 1 as you mentioned in comments, since the parallel circuit looks purely resistive when its admittance is real.

Comment: Of course, but would that necessarily result in maximum impedance as seen by the source? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: In a simple RLC parallel combination it will. But in, say, an LC parallel combination where one of the active elements has a (paraisitic) series resistance, then I believe the frequency of purely real admittance and the frequency of minimum magnitude of admittance will be different. (But I haven't gone back and re-worked the math to check)